# How to remove webpage extension from URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to remove webpage extension from URL,somebody gave me the code for .htaccess.
But it works on localhost when I turn on rewrite module.But when I use it on Godaddy it doen't work.and also when I visit example.com/cool.php it says 404 not found But I want it to be redirect if some visit example.com/cool.php to example.com/cool....
and also help about godaddy rewrite module I contacted them they haven't replied me yet. 
Here below is the code the guy gave to me..Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]


# remove index
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to show the "pretty" URL (`example.com/cool`) but still get the data from the original request (`example.com/cool.php`), you may try this in the .htaccess file at root directory:

#### Updated to work with php files at any directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Get the URI-path directly from THE_REQUEST variable
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/(.*)\.php [NC]
# Strip the extension and redirect permanently
RewriteRule  .*   /%2   [R=301,L,NC]

# Now the browser's address bar shows: http://example.com/cool

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php  [NC]
# Map internally to the original resource
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/?   /$1.php  [L,NC]

# Maps silently to: http://example.com/cool.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the URL redirects to example.com/cool from example.com/cool.php...BUT after redirection the page display's 404 Page not found error.both in localhost and livepage...Please help :D
BTW the code work for removed .php extension BUT it wont redirect and also it doesn't work on godaddy.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

Comment: Could you please replace the [L,NC] flags in the last rule with [R,L,NC] to **see** the mapped URL and copy+paste it into a comment.

Comment: Checking the edited comment, this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is not in my answer. Please replace the complete rule-set in your question with the one in my answer, without modification.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
is just the example that worked for me earlier but it doesn't work on godaddy Apache server,Now when I replace [L,NC] to [R,L,NC],it redirects completely to to index page in localhost and in live page it displays domain.com/domainname[example.com/example].

Comment: Ok here, after combining you're code and previous code this works BUT please could you help me in resolving the godaddy rewrite module problem.
HERE is the code work for me

# Map internally to the original resource[Changed to this code]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

Comment: Where are the .htaccess file and `cool.php`, at root or at `cool` directory?

Comment: Both are in the root directory...BTW I have multiple domain does that effect it.

Comment: AND also when I visited the style.css page it display in the source code as style.css.php...Adding URL path resolves this problem but ../style.css add's style.css.php..Thanks

Comment: I am sorry,Actually you're earlier first code work's now...I just added the .htaccess file in the secondary domains root directory.BUT still all the .css/.js file at the end it adds .php [eg.example.com/style.css.php]...what to do about it...:D

Comment: Modified my answer to exclude all existing files and directories from the rules. If it doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: when i use localhost/style.css it adds style.css.php
when i use ../style.css it also add style.css.php
when i use http://www.example.com/style.css it also adds style.css.php
and also it also adds to javaScript file all image links working fine...

Comment: It shouldn't. The 2 conditions exclude all existing files. Please make sure the browser's cache is clear before any test.

Comment: Thanks it's working now everything is displaying fine...Live site have no problem [link](http://www.webtasium.com/iamcool.php) BUT in localhost page are not display getting 404 error.THANKS

Comment: Spoke to soon I guess..sorry, but when i visit webtasium.com/iamcool.php it works great everything is fine but when I go to other deep directories it gives me 404 error...here [link](http://www.webtasium.com/text/html/doctype.php)...WOW after one solution new problem arrives,thats why I love web developing.:D

Comment: Modified. Give it a try.

Comment: not working..same problem.Gives me this error..Not Found

The requested URL /text.php[<<<<<<<I think problem is here] was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: When I go to the link in your previous question, the 1st rule is used because the URL becomes `http://www.webtasium.com/text/html/doctype`, without the extension. But the second rule only matches the first level, so the extension is appended to text.

Comment: The reason for that is the first rule is different from the one in my answer. Seems like the one in the question, which is okay, but in that case the 2nd rule has to be modified accordingly. Try replacing `^([^/]+)/?$` with `^(.*)/?` and it should work for all php files in any directory. Haven't test it, though. Didn't do it that way because I thought you only needed to rewrite the files in one directory, according to the question.

Comment: No other rules applied beside you're...BUT still not working BUT now I am getting this error

Not Found

The requested URL /text/html/doctype was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Hey just changed to this 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA] ...Now its working check it out..Hurray

Comment: That's what I was mentioning in my last comments, in case you didn't get it from them. It was not easy, though.

Comment: Thank God that language's like HTML and PHP are not as difficult as .htaccess..actually I didn't understand a single thing in .htaccess code...Thanks a lot for helping me..You are very talented guy and thanks for you're time...:D