# Removing .php extension from URLs using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url, clean-urls

Is it possible to remove the .php part from all of my URLs using a **.htaccess** file?

Two examples:

```
http://url.com/home.php
http://url.com/shops.php
```

Become:

```
http://url.com/home/
http://url.com/shops/
```

All the help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean in the extra?

Comment: @Servant im wanting to merge 2 links together, im going to be having about 10 shops and it would look better if each shop was in a category and so I don't mind making a new directory with the shop names inside.  
Example:  
  
shops.php  
Shops-Folder>shopName1,shopName2  
url.com/shops/shopname1/  
url.com/shops/shopname2/

Comment: What? Do you want to rewrite */$var1/$var2.php* into */$var1/$var2/* ?

Comment: @Servant I think its just to hard to explain and probs impossible. Thanks for your time but i'l edit the extra out.

Comment: No, it's possible.. I'll try it, just wait for my answer..

Comment: @Servant This would be a lot easier to explain in chat, come into PHP please.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996464/how-to-remove-webpage-extension-from-url/15996788#15996788). I think it does exactly what you need..

Comment: @faa WOW Thanks worked! but I would like url.com/home/ with the extra slash on the end, could you help me with that please? Thanks again!

Comment: Go to: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28210/servant

Comment: It's my answer, so just replace this `RewriteRule  .*   /%2   [R=301,L,NC]` with this `RewriteRule  .*   /%2/   [R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: @faa I keep getting url.com// (2 slashes)

Comment: @faa and when I keep old changes I still get the double //'s on /home so /home becomes url.com//

Comment: But the trailing slash is being added as expected? Remove the leading slash, like this `%2/`and see what happens.

Comment: @faa try this: http://rahulkhosla.co.uk im using `RewriteRule  .*   /%2   [R=301,L,NC]` then try http://rahulkhosla.co.uk/home

Comment: I get `http://rahulkhosla.co.uk/home` and `http://rahulkhosla.co.uk/shops`. No problem. I am using Firefox 20.0.1 Make sure the browser's cache is cleared.

Comment: @RahulKhosla My answer is updated!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \/([^\/]+)\/$ $1.php
```

It will serve you the file named after the last segment of the url:

http://example.com/shops/shopname1/ -> shopname1.php

http://example.com/shops/ -> shops.php

Answer (score 3):

To rewrite */$var/* into */$var.php* and then redirect */$var.php* into */$var/* just use these directives in your *.htaccess* file:

```
# once per htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/? /$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+).php$ /$1/ [R]
```

And if you also want to rewrite the specific URL */shops/shopName1/* into the specific URL */shopName1.php* and then redirect */shopName1.php* into */shops/shopName1/* then you should use this code below instead the code above:

```
# once per htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /$1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName1.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+).php$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^shops/shopName1/?$ /shopName1.php
RewriteRule ^shopName1.php$ /shops/shopName1/ [R]
```

But remember there's no variable on */shops/shopName1/*, give it a try, if you want..

---

It seems there's a problem about redirection with `DirectoryIndex home.php`. But I think, this is the code that you want, but in this time, we excluded any redirection:

```
DirectoryIndex /home.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName1/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName2/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName3/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName4/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shopName5/?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ /$1.php

RewriteRule ^shops/shopName1/?$ /shopName1.php
RewriteRule ^shops/shopName2/?$ /shopName2.php
RewriteRule ^shops/shopName3/?$ /shopName3.php
RewriteRule ^shops/shopName4/?$ /shopName4.php
RewriteRule ^shops/shopName5/?$ /shopName5.php
```

Just use your logic to add more conditions and rules..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply stop using regular .php files for pages and instead of a framework or a request router, however if you really do want to do this, then in order to get `shops.php` to `shops` you need to create a .htaccess file and add the following to it:

```
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

This will rename all of the `something.php` to `something` on the URL bar.

An example of a complete `.htaccess` file would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do I also write `RewriteEngine on` before those lines?

Comment: Yes `RewriteEngine On` before the two lines.

Comment: I added an example of a complete .htaccess file.

Comment: @Askp Foe
Ok this is my complete .htaccess file:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex home.php`

I keep getting this:

`http://rahulkhosla.co.uk/home/.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php`

Comment: I just edited that 10 times, yet cant find out how <br/>'s work sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: Instead of `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1.php [L,R=301]` try Rick's `RewriteRule \/([^\/]+)\/$ $1.php`

Comment: Didn't work, still same problem.

Comment: Try removing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]`

Comment: I just updated my original answer with better code, try the above again.

Comment: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/(home|shops) /$1.php
```

second only manual

```
RewriteRule ^/shops/shopname1/ /whateveryouneed.php
```