# .htaccess multiple RewriteRule's doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The multiple RewriteRule's doesn't work into my .htaccess file.

To get direct into the point, i have this lines of code into my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ./profile.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The problem is when i add a parameter into my domain, let's suppose www.eaxmple.com/something, i land always to home page. What i want to do is when i set a parameter with slash at the end to go to profile.php and without slash to move into index.php. Even if i tried to put a parameter i always move to index page.

Can someone help me?

Comment: see here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003269/removing-php-extension-from-urls-using-htaccess][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` will match everything including trailing `/`.

Try rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L][

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ profile.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```