# Remove url extension from webpage on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I want to remove url extension form webpage on localhost. i see at your website how to do it and i also search on internet how to do it but i can't success on it.Help me

no change on webpage url and it don't work. i use Apache server and i put this`.htaccess` file in `www` folder but it is not working.

so what can i do?

my `.htaccess` file contain following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Do you want do this only on localhost?

Comment: look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996464/how-to-remove-webpage-extension-from-url